# How to JOIN this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two tables:

Topics, Articles and Discover

In the `Topics` table I have: `'id', 'title'`
In the `Articles` table I have: `'id', 'title'`
In the `Discover` table I have: `'id', 'itemId', 'itemType', 'hOrder'`

In the `Discover` table pretty much I want to store in `itemId` the id of a `Topic` or an `Article`. In `itemType` I would have a '`p`' or an '`a`' depending on what it is (topic or article respectively).

My problem is when I try to pull the values. I want to make a `JOIN` that would get me all the `Topics` and IF the topic is in the `Discover` table, it would give me the `hOrder`.

I tried doing this

```
SELECT *
FROM playlists p
LEFT JOIN homepage_discover h
ON p.id = h.itemId
WHERE h.itemType = 'p'
```

And i tried INNER, LEFT, RIGHT joins and none is what I'm looking for. What type of JOIN would that be? Thanks!

Comment: `p` or `a`: Is `p` indicative of a `Topic` assuming `a` is an `Article`?

Comment: Yes, sorry about that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using outer joins, where clause values must only relate to the table having all the records to be returned.  Otherwise you limit out the null values desired by the outer join.  This can be accomplished by either using a "and is null notation" in the where clause or "adding the limiting criteria to the join itself".

The reason this works has to do with order of execution within the join and the cartean product generated.  When the system joins T to D it excludes anything with itemtype not p. then the outer join is performed thereby not eliminating records from the topic.  When this is done in the where clause, the join has already occurred so all records are evaluated for itemtype p. some of which will be NULL therefor excluded, eliminating the outer join and thus why using an or is null works!

```
SELECT *
FROM Topics T
LEFT JOIN Discover D 
 on T.ID = D.itemID and d.itemType = 'p'
```

OR

```
SELECT *
FROM Topics T
LEFT JOIN Discover D 
 on T.ID = D.itemID 
WHERE (D.itemType = 'p' or D.itemType is null)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it this way, you could use

```
SELECT 
   t.*,
   d.hOrder
FROM 
    topic t
LEFT JOIN             -- we want all topics
    discover d
ON
    t.id = d.itemId
AND
    d.itemType = 'p'  -- because 'p' indicates a topic
```

Personally I wouldn't mix the relations this way. I would use separate columns.

Comment: I imagine I would have to write a different question, but is there a quick reason why?

Comment: Shouldn't it be a left join?

Comment: @xQbert: you're right. I missed "get me *all* the Topics"

Comment: @raygo: most queries will get simpler. It's only one condition that's got to be checked.